# How to assign a timezone to a DateTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone, dst

I am getting a date/time value in the form of a string which I am casting to a `DateTime` object.

```
eg. 2012-11-10 11:37:06
```

I know that this time is from a different timezone to the local time of my system.

How can I assign a timezone to the `DateTime` object so that I can represent the time accurately in my local timezone as well as be sensitive to daylight savings changes?

Comment: DateTime does not have timezone only an offest.

Comment: @Blam: `DateTime` doesn't even have an offset as part of its data...

Comment: @JonSkeet With a ToString you can get the offset with a zzz.  If that is not part of DateTime then where is is coming from?  In your answer you seem to imply there is an offset.

Answer (score 0):

[TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  will probably do what you want.

This way you can convert (on import) and store all times as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (assuming you know what time zone daylight savings offset, etc, the original time associates with) and display them in whatever timezone after that.  I've linked to the overload method which takes both a `DateTime` and a `TimeZoneInfo` object.

There are other methods in `TimeZoneInfo` which are useful for such conversions as well.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` isn't a time zone, and doesn't fully *know* a time zone. It has a `Kind`, which indicates whether it's in the system time zone (`Local`), UTC (`Universal`) or "something else" (`Unspecified`).

There's `DateTimeOffset`, which is like a `DateTime` but also with an offset from UTC. That's not the same as having a time zone though - it doesn't know what the local time would be at any other point in time.

I'm biased, but I'd suggest using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which has all kinds of types to represent different concepts:

- `ZonedDateTime` - a local date/time in a particular time zone, with an offset from UTC just in case of ambiguity
- `OffsetDateTime` - a local date/time with an offset from UTC (but no specific time zone)
- `LocalDateTime` - just a local date/time, with no specific time zone or offset
- `LocalDate` - a date with no time component or zone
- `LocalTime` - just a time of date, with no date or zone

All of these also have an associated calendar system (unlike `DateTime`). For an instant in time, there's `Instant` which is just a number of ticks from the Unix epoch.

If you want to stick to BCL types, you can keep a `DateTime` with a `TimeZoneInfo` in your own data type.